# How to pass a large array to cakephp shell from a controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to pass a large array containing emails as parameters to a cakephp shell.
I am not sure as to which approach to use -

1. Use an array model to store the data and read the model in the shell.
2. Pass the array values as an argument while calling the shell.
3. Store the array in cache and access from shell.

I am executing the shell using shell_exec.

It will be good if you point me which approach to use or if there is a better approach for coding ?

Comment: Why would you do this? Are you sure you don't want your "shell code" in the Model and invoke the Model from your shell instead? It sounds like a bad approach.

Comment: I want to run a long task over those emails, and shell is something that can run as a  background task. My question is how do I store those emails temporarily so that I can access them in a cakephp shell ?

Comment: Instead of sending it to your shell, can't you program your shell in a way that it grabs it's own data? So that it can run on its own?

Comment: User creates the data in the controller, and data needs to be sent to shell for background processing !

Comment: Why is a php process calling a php process via exec? That should be an obvious indicator that it's not the best/right way to do things.

Comment: Sometimes you need to kick off a process that will take a long time and you don't want the user to wait for it to finish in order to load/reload a page. Therefore the only option is to kick off a shell and show the user a progress indicator until it's finished. You can store the array in cache, but if you have multiple users doing this it might cause data collisions. The safer way is to store your info in a DB and pass IDs along to your shell.

Comment: If a process is started via exec - you either waits for it to finish or find that when sent to the background it dies as soon as the parent php process does (or attempt to nohup it - but that's simply messy). There's no substitute for using a real background job solution (e.g. gearman) to implement "do something but don't make the user wait for it to finish"..

Comment: Agreed. We use SOS Job Scheduler to do stuff like that. It'll kick off the shell job, return a process ID that you can track via AJAX requests to see if it's finished running, and use that to update your user's UI.

Comment: I used cakephp cache to store my data and deleted the cached values after reading them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get your array from your controller's action:

```
App::import('Core', array('View', 'Controller', 'Model', 'Router'));
App::import('Controller', 'YourController');
$YourController =& new YourControllerController();
$YourController->constructClasses();
$YourController->layout = null; 
$this->out(call_user_func(array($NewsletterController, 'yourAction')));
```